# DataList to PDF Export

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ascx

I have an ASCX control which displays a tag cloud (red and green tags using a datalist). Is there a way to export this datalist to a PDF file, preserving both the tag size and its color? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use a PDF library for .NET. The best example is probably [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).
The book [iText in Action](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/) is also well worth the investment and will get you up and running with the iText .NET API quickly.

Create a PDF version of your tag cloud in addition to your ASCX/HTML version, rather than trying to convert an HTML fragment to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    datalist1.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GenerateReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dr = GetData("SELECT * FROM Employees where EmployeeId = " + ddlEmployees.SelectedItem.Value).Rows[0]; ;
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
    Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        Phrase phrase = null;
        PdfPCell cell = null;
        PdfPTable table = null;
        Color color = null;

        document.Open();

        //Header Table
        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.TotalWidth = 500f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.3f, 0.7f });

        //Company Logo
        cell = ImageCell("~/images/northwindlogo.gif", 30f, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Company Name and Address
        phrase = new Phrase();
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Microsoft Northwind Traders Company\n\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 16, Font.BOLD, Color.RED)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("107, Park site,\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Salt Lake Road,\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Seattle, USA", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.ALIGN_TOP;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Separater Line
        color = new Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A9A9A9"));
        DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 79f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 79f, color);
        DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 80f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 80f, color);
        document.Add(table);

        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.3f, 1f });
        table.SpacingBefore = 20f;

        //Employee Details
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase("Employee Record", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.UNDERLINE, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 30f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Photo
        cell = ImageCell(string.Format("~/photos/{0}.jpg", dr["EmployeeId"]), 25f, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Name
        phrase = new Phrase();
        phrase.Add(new Chunk(dr["TitleOfCourtesy"] + " " + dr["FirstName"] + " " + dr["LastName"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("(" + dr["Title"].ToString() + ")", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
        cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        document.Add(table);

        DrawLine(writer, 160f, 80f, 160f, 690f, Color.BLACK);
        DrawLine(writer, 115f, document.Top - 200f, document.PageSize.Width - 100f, document.Top - 200f, Color.BLACK);

        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.5f, 2f });
        table.TotalWidth = 340f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

        //Employee Id
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Employee code:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("000" + dr["EmployeeId"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);


        //Address
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Address:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Address"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk(dr["City"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk(dr["Region"] + " " + dr["Country"] + " " + dr["PostalCode"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Date of Birth
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Date of Birth:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["BirthDate"]).ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy"), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Phone
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Phone Number:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase(dr["HomePhone"] + " Ext: " + dr["Extension"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Addtional Information
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Addtional Information:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase(dr["Notes"].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED));
        document.Add(table);
        document.Close();
        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Employee.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
        Response.Close();
    }
}

private static void DrawLine(PdfWriter writer, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, Color color)
{
    PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
    contentByte.SetColorStroke(color);
    contentByte.MoveTo(x1, y1);
    contentByte.LineTo(x2, y2);
    contentByte.Stroke();
}
private static PdfPCell PhraseCell(Phrase phrase, int align)
{
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
    cell.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.ALIGN_TOP;
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = align;
    cell.PaddingBottom = 2f;
    cell.PaddingTop = 0f;
    return cell;
}
private static PdfPCell ImageCell(string path, float scale, int align)
{
    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));
    image.ScalePercent(scale);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(image);
    cell.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.ALIGN_TOP;
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = align;
    cell.PaddingBottom = 0f;
    cell.PaddingTop = 0f;
    return cell;
}
```